# Обработчики событий js

Tags: javascript, slider-sly.js

Использую плагин sly js для горизонтального скроллинга элементов. Есть такая вёрстка (просто как пример):

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на определённый элемент списка происходило нужное мне событие? Проблема в том, что если я вешаю событие на "click", то всё работает, но есть одно но:
click срабатывает даже тогда, когда я просто перемещаю элементы мышью (скроллю). Как сделать так, чтобы только при нажатии на элемент (без перетаскивания) срабатывало событие?

Comment: это должно быть реализовано на уровне скрипта. мы сейчас можем сделать костыль, но не факт, что не сломаем костылем логику. посмотрите примеры, возможно там есть нужное. а вообще все просто: учет клика только если между нажатием и отпусканием кнопки мышь не перемещалась или мало перемещалась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение: вместо события click использую кастомное событие изменения класса, так как при нажатии на элемент в скроллере его класс меняется на active. Может это и костыль, но пока проблем не замечено, всё отлично работает.